# Migrating to Office365 - Accessing Outlook folders via Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, office365

Our organization is migrating to Office 365. Currently we have an MS Access tool which is extracting public folder calendar data using a vba code shown below. Is there any changes to the code, if it is in O365 environment?

```
Set myns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set mycal = myns.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders).Folders("foldername").Folders("subfoldername")
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It will work - you don't need to do any changes.